# Why won't Palantir QS 3.8 recognise its own XML export?

Tags: java, xml

Hello Palantir community on StackOverflow - if you exist?

I'm having a problem with pXML and PXZ files on a QuickStart instance (see below for details).  If I export from Graph (even if only a few relatively small Objects), then try and reimport that file, I get the error message,

> Error: The file [file path & name] is not a valid .pxz file:
>   com.palantir.exceptionPalantirUserMessageException.  Unexpected error
>   while validating PalantirXML; please see the log for details.

The log will then give some version of,

> Value " with length = '0' is not faced-valid with respect to minLength
>   '1' for type #AnonType_namedataSource;.

Multiple Java error references will then follow (195, 131, 384, 318, etc).

So this seems to be an issue with Palantir writing an XML file badly, then not recognising it when you try to reimport.

The XML file itself seems ok - it's not very small, all the XML tags close off, etc.  But clearly there's a value somewhere that's meant to be a positive, and it's not being populated in the correct way.  The errant tag isn't obvious, if that's the case.

Weirdly, I can usually export a single Object (or maybe two or three) - but not if the Object is too complex (eg has lots of Properties).

I'm using an installation of Palantir Quick Start 3.8 (3.8.2.8.603030, Java Version: 1.6.0_30 Sun Microsystems Inc. - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM build 20.5-b03 64-bit).

I've tried various configurations of Java updates (6.3 32 & 64, 7.25 32 & 64, no Java update (Pal 3.8 comes with 6.3).

The computer is an Intel, 2.7 Ghz with 16 GB of RAM, running Windows 7 (SP1), 64bt.

I tried disabling the AV (McAfee) and Windows firewall - no difference.

I'll leave it there for now - very grateful for any advice / suggestions.

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an old version of Palantir! I worked on the code you're seeing errors with through many versions of Gotham. The problem is that the first step in the import process is validating the pXML against its .xsd file. While writing, the library makes sure the XML is syntactically valid, but doesn't verify it against the schema.

That error makes it sound like a DataSource is missing some value that's required by the schema. Exporting from a new Investigation may work, but this bug would need to be fixed by a Palantir developer.

You could also try it later version where it may be fixed already.